# How do display a boostrap/angularUI alert always on top?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying some alerts using [angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which is basically powered by bootstrap. However the issue is that the alerts can't be seen by the client if they are navigating to the bottom of the page. I would like to know how can I display the alerts always on top ( I think the right term is "on fixed position" )

Answer (score 7):

How exactly do you want it to work?  It might be easiest to use a library like [PNotify](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/#demos-simple) or [AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) [(***plnkr***)](http://plnkr.co/edit/lCEDLtUI8P73MBrvKYou?p=preview).

[image]

If you want to do it yourself, you could put them in a special area.  For something like this you can put the alerts in a div that is `position:fixed` ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/qw6HcWb7CenjVJ18t0x3?p=preview)):

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">
      {{alert.msg}}
  </alert>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I need ! Any idea how can I display it on full width on top ? The client may miss it if is placed on corners.

Comment: Just add `width: 100%` or `left: 0` to the div

Answer (score 0):

well, you should add or override alert styles with `position:fixed` if you want to "pin" it to the screen..
with additional properties `left` and `top` for positioning relative to viewport.

Answer (score 0):

There are various css position properties that will help you.

```
.class_of_your_alerts {
    position: absolute; /* position: absolute rather than position: fixed 
                           because you will be declaring left, right, top, etc. */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; /* now it covers the whole browser window because all absolute
                  positioning properties are set to 0. Tweak to your liking
                  using px or percentage */

    z-index: 105; /* optional - if your application has a lot of layers that are 
                     already absolutely positioned, you may wish to up the z-index
                     which is essentially the element stacking order for the current
                     dom node */
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute` can place them on top of other items, but it scrolls with the page.  hey wants them to appear at the top of the window even if the page is scrolled down.