# How to show bootstrap alerts on top

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap alerts to show success and error messages.  I wanted to overlay these alerts on the top of another `div`.
There are few SO posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985634/how-do-display-a-boostrap-angularui-alert-always-on-top)) i read which suggests to use `postion:fixed`  However that does not work for me. There 2 things need to happen in my scenario.

1> All the alerts needs to be on the top of another `div`. *(I think in my case the alerts are hiding under because of the background color im setting in `mt-form-panel` class. However we need some background color for content div )*

2> `alert-success` needs to be on the top of `alert-danger`

I have the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/350msyxL/10/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `z-index`to bring the alerts to the front.

Something like this:

```
.mt-alerts {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index:1000` to get the `.mt-alerts` show up on top of `.mt-form-panel`.

For point 2 you can do two things.

A) As by the looks of it, it seems that only 1 alert would be showing up at one time and both cannot show up together. In this case you can set `display:none;` on both alerts as default and set them back to `display:block` when there respective code condition is meet.

B) You can use `position:absolute` along with margins and specific width to position both the alerts at the same place.